# Compare and contrast adaptive quadrature and Gaussian quadrature.

Tags: numerical-methods

Compare and contrast adaptive quadrature and Gaussian quadrature.

what is mean by compare and contrast i know the method of adaptive and Gaussian quadrature.

Can any one help me in this problem

Answer (score 1):

Examine the error estimates of both methods. Also, you could make comparisons between both methods, by using them to evaluate a specific integral, one in which there is an analytical answer. You could look at computation time to reach a specific degree of accuracy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/862151)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich The question is so broad that I am not sure that there *is* an answer.  steveqed's answer seems like a reasonable attempt...